# Order BY methods

Tags: oracle

In Oracle SQL developer, I have two columns that need to be ordered by:

One Column name is OLD_TABLE_NAME with all the old table names. 
Another column name is NEW_TABLE_NAME with all the new table names listed

What I need to do is 
Order the table list by
1)  NEW_TABLE_NAME that have a matched OLD_TABLE_NAME

2)  NEW_TABLE_NAME that have no matched OLD_TABLE_NAME(NEW_TABLE_NAME would have names but the OLD_TABLE_NAME would be null)

3)  OLD_TABLE_NAME that have no matched NEW_TABLE_NAME (OLD_TABLE_NAME column would have names, but the NEW_TABLE_NAME column would be NULL)

Comment: Welcome to SO; here you find [ask].Please post some sample data, desired result and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, but I understood it like you want to order first by matching movie and director and then by matching movie and then the rest:

```
order by case when movie = :movie and director = :director then 1
              when movie = :movie then 2
              else 3 end
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. This is close but I'm not using variables. When I took the @ symbol out the SQL script did organize the columns, but I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: @K.O., can you shou some simple data and what result you are expecting from it?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - I stand by my comment. If you had time to check syntax after my comment, you could have done exactly the same before posting. Fix your post and I will take back my downvote. To explain my position: There is already a lot of garbage on SO from novices; we don't need experienced players doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from (
select 1 as rank, movie as movie, director as director
from yourtable
where director is not null

union all

select 2, movie, ''
from yourtable
where director is null) movies

order by rank, movie asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bind variables for the required movie and director values:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table_name
WHERE    movie    = :movie
OR       director = :director
ORDER BY movie    NULLS LAST,
         director NULLS LAST
```

Comment: @K.O. Would you care to give an example (by editing your question) of your sample data and the expected output and letting me know how "this did not work". Just stating "this did not work" is not constructive in helping me to find something that will work.